# How can I compare two strings and return the lexicographical ordered result using the compareTo method?

Tags: java, string, compare, getter, comparable

I am trying to use compareTo method to compare two different names. After running the first attempt the program terminates immediately without returning anything. How can I modify this compareTo method to compare the names (Name n and Name n2) and return the result (-1, 1 or 0)? And obviously a print statement can be added to display (equal, before , or after) for the comparison. Thanks for any assistance.

```
//First attempt
public class Name implements Comparable<Name> {

    private String Name;

    public Name(String string) {
        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }
    public String getName() {
        return Name;
    }
    public int compareTo(Name other) {

        if (getName().compareTo(other.getName()) < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else if (getName().compareTo(other.getName()) > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (getName().equals(other.getName())) {
            return 0;
        }
        return getName().compareTo(other.getName());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Name n = new Name("jennifer");
        n.getName();
        Name n2 = new Name("paul");
        n2.getName();
    }
}




//second attempt
    public class Name implements Comparable<String> {

        private String Name;

        public String getName() {
            return Name;
        }
        public int compareTo(String other) {

            if (getName().compareTo(other.getName()) < 0) {
                return -1;
            } else if (getName().compareTo(other.getName()) > 0) {
                return 1;
            } else if (getName().equals(other.getName())) {
                return 0;
            }
            return getName().compareTo(other.getName());

        }
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            String Name = new String("jennifer");

            String other = new String("paul");
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's unclear what you're trying to do. And why don't you just `return getName().compareTo(other.getName())`? What are all the ifs for?

Comment: The if's are to compare whether or not the two names (Strings) are equal (lexicographically equivalent),  smaller - the String calling the method is lexicographically first (comes first in a dictionary), or larger (the parameter passed to the compareTo method is lexicographically first) . According to lexicographical order, which similar to the ordering that one might find in a dictionary.

Comment: You get that all out of the box by calling [`String.compareTo()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#compareTo(java.lang.String)).

Comment: Understood, just wanted to illustrate what's happening in the background. Thanks for the help and clarification!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//First attempt
public class Name {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String n = new String("jennifer");
        String n2 = new String("paul");
        if (n.compareTo(n2) < 0) {
            System.out.println(n +" is before than " +n2);
        } else if (n.compareTo(n2) > 0) {
            System.out.println(n +" is after than " +n2);
        } else if (n.compareTo(n2) == 0) {
            System.out.println(n +" is equals to " +n);
        }
    }   
}
```

Outoput:

```
jennifer is before than paul
```

By the way, [check this out](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/variables.html) because every programming language has its own set of rules and conventions and for variables in Java is like this:

> If the name you choose consists of only one word, spell that word in
>   all lowercase letters. If it consists of more than one word,
>   capitalize the first letter of each subsequent word.

Answer (score -1):

```
public class Name implements Comparable<Name> {

    private String name;

    public Name(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public int compareTo(Name other) {

        if (getName().compareTo(other.getName()) < 0) {
            return -1;
        } else if (getName().compareTo(other.getName()) > 0) {
            return 1;
        } else if (getName().equals(other.getName())) {
            return 0;
        }
        return getName().compareTo(other.getName());
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Name n = new Name("jennifer");
        n.getName();
        Name n2 = new Name("paul");
        n2.getName();
       System.out.println(n.getName());
      System.out.println(n2.getName());
       System.out.println(n2.compareTo(n));

    }
}
```

OUTPUT :
 jennifer
paul
1